# Multiple invokable constructors in Storm Flux

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-storm-flux

I'm using Storm Flux (0.10.0) DSL to deploy the following topology (simplified to keep only the relevant parts of it):

```
---
name: "my-topology"

components:
  - id: "esConfig"
    className: "java.util.HashMap"
    configMethods:
      - name: "put"
        args:
          - "es.nodes"
          - "${es.nodes}"

bolts:
  - id: "es-bolt"
    className: "org.elasticsearch.storm.EsBolt"
    constructorArgs:
      - "myindex/docs"
      - ref: "esConfig"
    parallelism: 1

# ... other bolts, spouts and streams here
```

As you can see, one of the bolts I use is `org.elasticsearch.storm.EsBolt` which has the following constructors ([see code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/blob/master/storm/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/storm/EsBolt.java#L61)):

```
public EsBolt(String target) { ... }
public EsBolt(String target, boolean writeAck) { ... }
public EsBolt(String target, Map configuration) { ... }
```

The last one should be called because I pass a String and a Map in the constructorArgs. But when I deploy the topology I get the following exception, as if Flux wasn't able to infer the right constructor from the types (String, Map):

```
storm jar mytopology-1.0.0.jar org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --local mytopology.yml --filter mytopology.properties

...
Version: 0.10.0
Parsing file: mytopology.yml
958  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - loading YAML from input stream...
965  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Performing property substitution.
969  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Not performing environment variable substitution.
1252 [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Detected DSL topology...
1431 [main] WARN  o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Found multiple invokable constructors for class class org.elasticsearch.storm.EsBolt, given arguments [myindex/docs, {es.nodes=localhost}]. Using the last one found.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildObject(FluxBuilder.java:291)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildBolts(FluxBuilder.java:372)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildTopology(FluxBuilder.java:88)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.Flux.runCli(Flux.java:153)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.Flux.main(Flux.java:98)
```

Any idea about what could be happening? Here is [how Storm Flux finds a compatible constructor](https://github.com/ptgoetz/flux/blob/master/flux-core/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/flux/FluxBuilder.java#L377). The magic is in the `canInvokeWithArgs` method.

These are Flux debug logs, where you see how FluxBuilder finds the most appropriate constructor:

```
Version: 0.10.0
Parsing file: mytopology.yml
559  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - loading YAML from input stream...
566  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Performing property substitution.
569  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Not performing environment variable substitution.
804  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Detected DSL topology...
org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger@3b69e7d1
1006 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Found constructor arguments in definition: java.util.ArrayList
1006 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Checking arguments for references.
1010 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Target class: org.elasticsearch.storm.EsBolt
1011 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - found constructor with same number of args..
1011 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Comparing parameter class class java.lang.String to object class class java.lang.String to see if assignment is possible.
1011 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Yes, they are the same class.
1012 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - ** invokable --> true
1012 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - found constructor with same number of args..
1012 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Comparing parameter class class java.lang.String to object class class java.lang.String to see if assignment is possible.
1012 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Yes, they are the same class.
1012 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - ** invokable --> true
1012 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Skipping constructor with wrong number of arguments.
1012 [main] WARN  o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Found multiple invokable constructors for class class org.elasticsearch.storm.EsBolt, given arguments [myindex/docs, {es.nodes=localhost}]. Using the last one found.
1014 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Found something seemingly compatible, attempting invocation...
1044 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Comparing parameter class class java.lang.String to object class class java.lang.String to see if assignment is possible.
1044 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - They are the same class.
1044 [main] DEBUG o.a.s.f.FluxBuilder - Comparing parameter class boolean to object class class java.util.HashMap to see if assignment is possible.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildObject(FluxBuilder.java:291)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed on Nov 18, 2015.

See this: https://github.com/apache/storm/commit/69b9cf581fd977f6c28b3a78a116deddadc44014

And the next version of Storm with this fix should be released within a month.

Answer (score 0):

As a crappy workaround, I've finally extended `EsBolt` to expose only the constructors I need and avoid collisions.

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.util.Map;
import org.elasticsearch.storm.EsBolt;

public class EsBoltWrapper extends EsBolt {

    public EsBoltWrapper(String target) {
        super(target);
    }

    public EsBoltWrapper(String target, Map configuration) {
        super(target, configuration);
    }
}
```

Now my topology looks like this:

```
bolts:
  - id: "es-bolt"
    className: "com.mypackage.EsBoltWrapper" # THE NEW CLASS
    constructorArgs:
      - "myindex/docs"
      - ref: "esConfig"
    parallelism: 1
```

It seems to be a bug in Storm Flux.